# Jquery Mobile Redirect Issue

Tags: jquery-mobile

Iam using jquery mobile 1.4.5

Here, Page is redirect automatically into last page and redirect count also increasing respectively.

For Page Redirection, I Have used following method but still same issue

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "dashboardPage.html");

$.mobile.changePage( "dashboard.html", {
                //transition: "pop",
                reverse: false,
                changeHash: false
              });

$.mobile.changePage( "dashboard.html");
```

My Issue is

For Ex:

I'm in Page 1, from page 1 i'll goto page 2, Then from there i come to page 1. Then again i goto page 2. So this time page2 is automatically redirect to page1.

If i switch between two pages, automatic page redirection increasing 1,2,3 time.

For switching pages, im using above page redirection method.

Comment: What does your page markup look like? How are you binding the events? Where are you calling the redirect?

Comment: I have same issues as mentioned in following link. But this still open issue in jqm  https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2369

Comment: Did you try addin "return false;" on the event that triggers the change?